# Retrieving data from MySQL in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim connect As String = "server=localhost;user=root;password=Password;database=giordydatabase"
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM students WHERE name =@firstName"
Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connect)
    Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()
        With sqlComm
            .Connection = sqlConn
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName")
        End With
        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
            While sqlReader.Read()
                ListBox.Text = sqlReader("Name").ToString()
            End While
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            ' add your exception here '
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

That's what I have done so far, I would like know how to retrieve the data and putting it into a ListBox.

Comment: `.AddWithValue` has 2 parameters - the second one for the value.

Comment: Nice job with the Using blocks. I think all this sql part should be in a `DAL`(Data Access Layer) with a method that returns your data.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I can see the statement as `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName")` but where is the Value for @firstName ?

use `.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", <Value for @firstName>)`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
ListBox.Text = sqlReader("Name").ToString()
```

To

```
ListBox.Items.Add(sqlReader("Name").ToString())
```